# Javascript assignment operators

Tags: javascript

Good day to SOF people, I'm new to this forum and also I'm learning how to code javascript. My question is how do assignment operators really work? I know (for example *= ) that

```
    var (nameOfVariable)=(value)
    nameOfVariable*=(some value)
```

is:

```
    nameOfVariable= nameOfVariable * (some value) == value*(some value)
```

Now for example:

```
    var value=2;
    console.log(value*=2); ==  4
```

So every n times I put (value*=2) in the console.log(),it gives me (value * 2^n) meaning,

```
    var value=2;
    console.log(value*=2); ==  4 (1st time)
    console.log(value*=2); ==  8 (2nd time)
    console.log(value*=2); == 2 * (2^n) == 16 (nth time)
```

I experimented this into a while loop and this is what happened:

```
    var value=2;          |  (Console gave me this) 
    while(value<=10){     |   2
    console.log(value);   |   4
    value*=2; }           |   8
    console.log(value);   |   16
```

Why is the assignment operator not exclusive in the brackets inside the "while" loop? Why does it affect the variable outside? Does it mean that everytime a variable involved in an assignment operator is written n times inside console.log(), it will return values 2^n(value) in my case? I'm hoping for an enlightment for this one because I know that to master programming means to master the fundamentals themselves.

Comment: it's the same variable inside the loop (which is **not** a closure at all) as outside

Comment: The while loop isn't a closure; it's a construct. There's no dedicated scope there - that applies with functions, not loops.

Comment: Ironically if there was a real closure you'd see the same behaviour because the variable `value` will become enclosed

Comment: oh my bad, that was unintentional :) I was thinking of those braces {} and not the closure itself. I have started JS since 2 days ago that's why there are a bunch of JS concepts I have to learn. Edit is the cure guys :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the assignment operator is not exclusive inside the loop is because of "scope."

You've instantiated the 'value' variable as 2 outside of the while loop so when you change the value of 'value' it assigns the new value to the instantiated variable.

[This guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/) should help.

Comment: Because of that "scope" I was able to access this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBwoFkRjZvE and everything seems clearer :), Thanks!